# Why fan speed/noise problem occuring on desktop with NVidia GeForce 9600 GT?

Tags: nvidia

I've read and tried every single thing suggested for solving this sort of problem in this forum and all over the internet and nothing worked, everything from changing grub configurations to installing jupiter and other fan controller software, cpufreqd and cpufrequtils, every single thing. The computer still keeps making too much noise, which doesn't happen when I run windows 7.

I'm running a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) 32bit and Windows 7, 
Kernel Linux 3.5.0-18-generic
GNOME 3.6.0

I have 2 GB RAM and an Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E4500 @ 2.20GHz × 2

my graphics card is NVidia GeForce 9600 GT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Nouveau (the built-in open source driver) or the proprietary Nvidia driver?

If you aren't using the latter - or aren't *absolutely sure* you're using the latter - please open the Dash, open Additional Drivers, and select and activate the driver marked `NVIDIA acclerated graphics driver (version current) [Recommended]`.

[image: additional drivers]

After downloading, installing, and activating the driver, a reboot will be required before it actually takes effect.  Good luck.

Comment: I am only getting 2 expermiental drivers and 4 other ones called NVIDIA Binary Xorg, kernel module and VDPAU library

Comment: ITS SOLVED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Really, I do owe you my mental health. I installed the driver that came from the "current" source and after rebooting the issue was settled.